# How to enable Ethernet interface?

Tags: boot, ethernet, dmesg

I have a problem with my Ethernet interface. I think this problem occur after I replaced my bios because of password.
The problem is, when I turn on my laptop after shutdown my Ethernet interface dose not work. But after restart it always work. 
I have these logs in dmesg file:

```
[    2.208804] kernel: e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    3.253199] kernel: e1000e: probe of 0000:00:19.0 failed with error -3
```

And These are in journal logs when it fails:

```
e1000e 0000:00:19.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
```

And These are in journal logs when it succeeds:

```
e1000e 0000:00:19.0 enp0s25: renamed from eth0
e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: MAC: 10, PHY: 11, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
e1000e 0000:00:19.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) Ab:cd:ef:ab:cd:ef
e1000e 0000:00:19.0 0000:00:19.0 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
```

Comment: Do you boot other systems?

Comment: No it's just ubuntu20.04

Comment: Can you add to your question the log entries for that device (there should be more than that) after shutdown (when it does not work) and after restart (when it does work)?

Comment: Where to find those logs?
I added some logs but I don't know if these are what you mean or not.